# Socket connection from emulated android phone to Python server

Tags: android, kotlin, sockets, connection, mobile-development

I am trying to establish a connection between a mobile app and a server. For testing purposes I have the server set up on the same machine. However, if I try to establish the connection through the app, the application crashes.

Server Code(taken from ChatGPT temporarily):

```
import socket

# Define the host and port to run the server
HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Use '0.0.0.0' to listen on all available interfaces
PORT = 8888

# Create a socket object
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the host and port
server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))

# Listen for incoming connections
server_socket.listen()

print(f"Server listening on {HOST}:{PORT}")

while True:
    # Accept incoming connection
    client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established!")

    # Handle incoming data from the client
    data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break

    print(f"Received data: {data.decode()}")

    # Send a response to the client
    client_socket.sendall("Data received by the server".encode())

# Close the connection
client_socket.close()
```

Connection code for the app written in Kotlin:

```
Thread
{
   val client = Socket(address,8888)
}.start()
```

The address is taken from the user as input. I've tried 127.0.0.1 and 10.0.2.2 for connection and neither worked. And any connection attempt with these IP addresses causes the app to crash.

When I try to connect to this server via a python client or a kotlin client ran on the same machine I don't have any issues. I've tried putting try catch blocks to see if there is an exception I'm missing but there is no exception being thrown either. Is the issue because the emulated device can't reach the server? If so, how can I proceed in order to test connection functionalities in the future? Also normally the server will be hosted on a different device, is there another method that would better suit my needs? I am new to mobile development and had limited network knowledge before this so I'm a bit lost.

EDIT:

Found out that I was running the wrong method in my connection manager which caused it to not establish connection when run on 10.0.2.2. Fixing that enabled the connection to go through. However the application still crashes when 127.0.0.1 is input.

Comment: Unclear which address you are using in Android app. See: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#networkaddresses

Comment: @MorrisonChang Forgot to mention that it is taken as user input. Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: If your app crashes you are not catching an exception that is thrown. Find out which one(s), catch them and tell us.

Comment: `HOST = '127.0.0.1'` That is wrong. Do not bind your server to an ip. And if you have to then to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: And the emulator client should use 10.0.2.2.

Comment: `When I try to connect to this server via a python client or a kotlin client I don't have any issues.` You forgot to tell where those clients are running.

Comment: @blackapps Using 10.0.2.2 and fixing the issue I mentioned in the edit solved the issue I had with not being able to connect. Apparently misunderstood the addresses in the https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#networkaddresses.